# XAML Convert textblock text to Inlines

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-10, uwp

I want to set this kind of text on TextBlock in a UWP project :

```
"<Bold>" + variable + "</Bold>"
```

But set it to Text value do not consider `<Bold>` tags.

So i searched how to do and the only one answer is "creat Inlines and add it to your textBlock".
but i don't want to do it on my View Model.

So i'm looking for a converter to replace my text attribute by a inlines collection to set on my textBlock.
I found some example (https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1a1af975-e186-4167-b1c9-cc86afcdd93a/how-to-show-text-in-textblock-as-rich-text-format?forum=wpf), but not working on universal Windows apps (UWP).

I tried this but i have an error (unable to cast Binding to string):

```
<TextBlock  x:Name="newsArticleSections"
                            Tag="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource TextToRunConverter}, ConverterParameter={Binding ArticleSections}}"/>
```

And this is my converter :

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        TextBlock textblock = value as TextBlock;

        textblock.ClearValue(TextBlock.TextProperty);
        Run run = new Run();
        run.Text = (string)parameter;
        textblock.Inlines.Add(run);
        return null;
    }
```

It's just the ways that i had explored, but with no result for the moment.
Does someone has another idea ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@devuxer answer was a good idea, but only for WPF project.
So i used it to make UWP solution and it works :

Create a Formatter class :

```
public class TextBlockFormatter
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty FormattedTextProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
    "FormattedText",
    typeof(string),
    typeof(TextBlockFormatter),
    new PropertyMetadata(null, FormattedTextPropertyChanged));

    public static void SetFormattedText(DependencyObject textBlock, string value)
    {
        textBlock.SetValue(FormattedTextProperty, value);
    }

    public static string GetFormattedText(DependencyObject textBlock)
    {
        return (string)textBlock.GetValue(FormattedTextProperty);
    }

    private static void FormattedTextPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Clear current textBlock
        TextBlock textBlock = d as TextBlock;
        textBlock.ClearValue(TextBlock.TextProperty);
        textBlock.Inlines.Clear();
        // Create new formatted text
        string formattedText = (string)e.NewValue ?? string.Empty;
        string @namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation";
        formattedText = $@"<Span xml:space=""preserve"" xmlns=""{@namespace}"">{formattedText}</Span>";
        // Inject to inlines
        var result = (Span)XamlReader.Load(formattedText);
        textBlock.Inlines.Add(result);
    }

}
```

And add this reference to your XAML file :

```
xmlns:helpers="using:MyProject.Helpers"
```

To use the formatter, simply add a TextBlock and declare your binding on FormattedText, like this :

```
<TextBlock  x:Name="textBlock" helpers:TextBlockFormatter.FormattedText="{Binding Content}">
```

Comment: Glad you were able to modify the code to work with UWP!

Comment: An extension to this question: How does the "variable" get passed into this? I can see the FormattedText being used isntead of the Text, but if a specific word is to be "bold" then how does one pass the word in xaml ?

Answer (score 5):

I've been using the following solution for WPF projects (not UWP), so I'm not sure if it will work for you, but feel free to give it a try.

You begin by putting the following into a class file within, say, a Helpers folder inside your project:

```
public class Formatter
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty FormattedTextProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "FormattedText",
        typeof(string),
        typeof(Formatter),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(string.Empty, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsMeasure, FormattedTextPropertyChanged));

    public static void SetFormattedText(DependencyObject textBlock, string value)
    {
        textBlock.SetValue(FormattedTextProperty, value);
    }

    public static string GetFormattedText(DependencyObject textBlock)
    {
        return (string)textBlock.GetValue(FormattedTextProperty);
    }

    private static void FormattedTextPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var textBlock = d as TextBlock;
        if (textBlock == null) return;
        const string @namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation";
        var formattedText = (string)e.NewValue ?? string.Empty;
        formattedText = $@"<Span xml:space=""preserve"" xmlns=""{@namespace}"">{formattedText}</Span>";

        textBlock.Inlines.Clear();
        using (var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(formattedText)))
        {
            var result = (Span)XamlReader.Load(xmlReader);
            textBlock.Inlines.Add(result);
        }
    }
}
```

Then, in your XAML file, reference the namespace, like so:

```
xmlns:helpers="clr-namespace:MyProject.Helpers"
```

To use the formatter, simply add a `TextBlock` and declare your binding on `FormattedText` (instead of `Text`), like this:

```
<TextBlock helpers:Formatter.FormattedText="{Binding Content}" />
```

Comment: It's a good idea, but "FrameworkPropertyMetadata" is not found in the UWP projects

Answer (score 1):

I use something like this:

XAML

```
<TextBlock Name="TB" Text="Bold Text " FontWeight="Bold"  />
```

At the Controller:

```
TB.Inlines.Add(new Run { Text = "New append text with diferent FontWeigth on the same TextBlock", FontWeight = FontWeights.Normal } );
```

Output will be:

**Bold Text** New append text with diferent FontWeigth on the same TextBlock

Answer (score 1):

I hope my contribution is still useful, or may be useful to other reaching this question. I've updated the Formatter class from @Geoffrey, so that specific characters in the `textblock` are tur**nin**g bold. I having a list with people and a search query at the top. The query part in name of the person is turning **bold**.

Query: ic
Result: R**ic**k

```
public class TextBlockFormatter
{
    const string @namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation";

    public static readonly DependencyProperty FormattedTextProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
    "FormattedText",
    typeof(string),
    typeof(TextBlockFormatter),
    new PropertyMetadata(null, FormattedTextPropertyChanged));

    public static void SetFormattedText(DependencyObject textBlock, string value)
    {
        textBlock.SetValue(FormattedTextProperty, value);
    }

    public static string GetFormattedText(DependencyObject textBlock)
    {
        return (string)textBlock.GetValue(FormattedTextProperty);
    }

    private static void FormattedTextPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var textBlock = (TextBlock)d;
        if (textBlock.DataContext == null)
        {
            textBlock.DataContextChanged += TextBlock_DataContextChanged;
            return;
        }

        var query = (string)e.NewValue ?? string.Empty;
        HighlightSearch(textBlock, query);
    }

    private static void HighlightSearch(TextBlock textBlock, string value)
    {
        var name = ((Person)textBlock.DataContext).Name;
        var query = value.ToUpper();

        var indexOfSearch = name.ToUpper().IndexOf(query, 0);

        if (indexOfSearch < 0) return;

        // add normal text first
        var firstText = name.Substring(0, indexOfSearch).Replace("&", "&amp;");
        var first = $@"<Span xml:space=""preserve"" xmlns=""{@namespace}"">{firstText}</Span>";
        var firstResult = (Span)XamlReader.Load(first);

        // add the bold text
        var boldText = name.Substring(indexOfSearch, query.Length).Replace("&", "&amp;");
        var bold = $@"<Bold xml:space=""preserve"" xmlns=""{@namespace}"">{boldText}</Bold>";
        var boldResult = (Bold)XamlReader.Load(bold);

        // add the rest of the text
        var restStartIndex = indexOfSearch + query.Length;
        var restText = name.Substring(restStartIndex, name.Length - restStartIndex).Replace("&", "&amp;");
        var rest = $@"<Span xml:space=""preserve"" xmlns=""{@namespace}"">{restText}</Span>";
        var restResult = (Span)XamlReader.Load(rest);

        // Clear current textBlock
        textBlock.ClearValue(TextBlock.TextProperty);
        textBlock.Inlines.Clear();

        // Inject to inlines
        textBlock.Inlines.Add(firstResult);
        textBlock.Inlines.Add(boldResult);
        textBlock.Inlines.Add(restResult);
    }

    private static void TextBlock_DataContextChanged(FrameworkElement sender, DataContextChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        var block = (TextBlock)sender;

        if (block.DataContext == null) return;

        block.DataContextChanged -= TextBlock_DataContextChanged;

        var query = (string)sender.GetValue(FormattedTextProperty);
        HighlightSearch(block, query);
    }
}
```

Use in XAML:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" helpers:TextBlockFormatter.FormattedText="{Binding ElementName=queryTextBox, Path=Text}"  />
```

I had some issues, For example my `datasource` was not set when the `FormattedTextPropertyChanged` was called. Also you need to take care of *escaping* the text. I made myself easy by using the `Replace` function.